# Samsung s7 battery drain

Tags: samsung, battery, battery-life

So my Samsung has been extremely overheating and not holding a charge. It went from 80 to 30 in under a hour. I checked the battery usage section in my settings and it say "10378" is using 81% of my battery. What the heck is "10378" and how do i stop it?

Answer (score 0):

It is an app you've uninstalled recently, if you restart the device that entry will clear.

Comment: It doesn't give me a choice to force quit or report, they are grayed out. The only text there is; CPU total 13h 46m 37s and Computed power usage 7239 mAh @Minty_Tiger

Comment: I thought it could of been a app I recently installed so I uninstalled it and restarted my phone. Doing that did nothing